# document.ready() causing an error in IE 8

Tags: jquery, load

I'm trying to use document.ready in IE 8 and I keep getting an error that "The object does not support this property" when I load the page.  I at the point where I'm simply trying to display an alert using document.read.  Here is the code I'm using:

In the Head tag I load the jquery file

in the script tag, that is located just before the body closing tag I have the following:

```
alert("typeof $: " + typeof $);
$(document).ready(function () { alert("Number One"); });
```

THe first alert tells me that $ is a function.  Then the error occurs once the browswer hits the document.ready line......

Does anyone have any ideas.  I'm hoping to load a script that will allow for the selecting and deselecting of check boxes in unique columns in a gridview.

Terry

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that another JavaScript library, loaded before JQuery, is using the `$` function for itself? Take a look at [`jQuery.noConflict();`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict).

Comment: Good call!  I make this a practice whether or not I initially have other libraries and on top of that I tend to call jQuery directly rather than the $ alias.  This helps prevent issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any other libraries that might conflict?

What does this do?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  alert("Number One");
});
```